MAUI app looks ugly in iOS but not in Android
I have developed a MAUI app. I did not use any special thing that depends on specific platform.
However, when I run the app in iOS Simulator, the first page I see is this ugly screen:

If I run it in Android simulator, this is the result (after correct authenticaton):


When the application is first launched, it should show these enrollment steps:

I check that condition using this instruction when app is launched:
public static async Task<bool> IsAuthenticated()
{
    var hasAuth = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("hasAuth");
    return !(hasAuth == null) && hasAuth.Equals("true");
}

As you see, I am using SecureStorage. I don't know why the iOS app is not visually acting the same way as Android.
Any hint, please?
EDIT:
App.xaml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeApp"
             xmlns:material="http://schemas.enisn-projects.io/dotnet/maui/uraniumui/material"
             x:Class="TimeApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <material:ColorResource />
                <ResourceDictionary x:Name="appStyles" Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
                <material:StyleResource BasedOn="{x:Reference appStyles}" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

AppShell.xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="TimeApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TimeApp.Controls"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TimeApp.Views"
    xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:TimeApp.Helpers"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeApp">

    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent
            Title="Cargando"
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
            Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
            FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LoadingPage}"
            Route="LoadingPage" />
        <ShellContent Route="LoginPage"
                      Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
                      Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
                      FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LoginPage}"/>
        <ShellContent
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
            Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
            Title="Jornada Laboral"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MainPage}"
            Route="MainPage">
            <ShellContent.Icon>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.Briefcase}" Color="Coral" Size="50"/>
            </ShellContent.Icon>
        </ShellContent>
        <ShellContent
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
            Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
            Title="Historia"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AsistenciaHistoricaPage}"
            Route="AsistenciaHistoricaPage">
            <ShellContent.Icon>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.History}" Color="MediumVioletRed" Size="50"/>
            </ShellContent.Icon>
        </ShellContent>
        <ShellContent
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
            Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
            Title="Definición de Turno"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:TurnoPage}"
            Route="TurnoPage">
            <ShellContent.Icon>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.Clock}" Color="IndianRed" Size="50"/>
            </ShellContent.Icon>
        </ShellContent>
        <ShellContent
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
            Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
            Title="Ubicación"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:UbicacionPage}"
            Route="UbicacionPage">
            <ShellContent.Icon>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.Map}" Color="SteelBlue" Size="50"/>
            </ShellContent.Icon>
        </ShellContent>
        <ShellContent
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
            Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
            Title="Enrolamiento"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:EnrolamientoPage}"
            Route="EnrolamientoPage">
            <ShellContent.Icon>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.User}" Color="Maroon" Size="50"/>
            </ShellContent.Icon>
        </ShellContent>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <MenuItem Text="Cerrar Sesión" Clicked="LogOut_Clicked">
        <MenuItem.IconImageSource>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.SignOut}" Color="Tomato" Size="50"/>
        </MenuItem.IconImageSource>
    </MenuItem>
    <Shell.FlyoutFooter>
        <controls:FooterControl />
    </Shell.FlyoutFooter>
</Shell>

MainPage.xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TimeApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TimeApp.Controls"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Controls;assembly=SkiaSharp.Extended.UI"
             x:Class="TimeApp.Views.MainPage"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:TimeApp.Helpers"
             x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="25" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <Label x:Name="Saludo" Text="" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
            <Label x:Name="Empresa" Text="" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
            <HorizontalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
                <Label Margin="0, 22, 10, 0" FontFamily="FontAwesomeRegular" Text="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.Calendar}"></Label>
                <Label Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" Text="{Binding CurrentDate, StringFormat='{0:dddd, d \\de MMMM \\de yyyy}'}" />
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
            <controls:AttendanceControl VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0, 20, 0, 20" />
            <controls:ShiftControl x:Name="shiftView" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, *">
                <Button Margin="10, 0, 10, 0" 
                        Grid.Column="0" 
                        Text="Entrada" 
                        BackgroundColor="Green" 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Clicked="EntradaButton_Clicked"/>
                <Button Margin="10, 0, 10, 0" 
                        Grid.Column="1" 
                        Text="Salida" 
                        BackgroundColor="Red" 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Clicked="SalidaButton_Clicked"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout
                x:Name="aiLayout"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.5">
            <ActivityIndicator Color="{StaticResource Primary}"
                               HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"
                               x:Name="Waiting" IsRunning="True" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="checkResult">
            <skia:SKLottieView
                Source="check_animated.json"
                RepeatCount="0"
                HeightRequest="200"
                WidthRequest="200"
                IsVisible="false"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <skia:SKLottieView
                Source="failed_animated.json"
                RepeatCount="0"
                HeightRequest="200"
                WidthRequest="200"
                IsVisible="false"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>

EDIT 2:
Demo project is at: https://github.com/jaimestuardo/help

there is absolutely no way for us to help you based on what you've provided.  Where is the relevant code/XAML?

What hint are you expecting? People who have problem with something looking "ugly" will post the screen shot, the relevant XAML, and example how they want it to look like. Anyway. From what I see, your problems are not related to how "ugly" or "pretty" this screen looks on IOS.

@Jason I have edited the question to show XAML files I think they are relevant. If you need to see somethng else, just ask me for it.

@H.A.H. I have edited the question. If you need something else, ask me for it.

Did only the shell flyout show ugly and the page show correctly on iOS?

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Nothing works. First, when shell is executed, it calls method IsAuthenticated shown in the question. If user is not authentcated, enrollment page should be shown. If he is, the main page should be shown. Please, refer to the Android screnshots.

Because your code is not completed, I can't reproduce your problem. I copied your code without <ShellContent.Icon> and <Shell.FlyoutFooter>. It displayed correctly.

How do you see it? Maybe you are seeing apparently good, but not doing what the application should do. I have uploaded full Visual Studio project to https://github.com/jaimestuardo/help. Can you take a look?

jstuardo Did you set the demo to public? When I open it, I get 404 error.

@user10627299 sorry.. please try again

I have cloned it but there is no sln file and when I build the csproj file, it failed.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT I have just downloaded the ZIP from GitHub. Uncompressed it. Double clicked in csproj file. Visual Studio was opened. Then compiled. It finished compiling correctly. Only warnings and a package restore issue were occured but project compiled anyway, What error did you encounter?

I used the Viusal Studio's clone function. I will try to download the zip.

Why I got into different page between android and ios when I debug it? In addition, I suggest you put the loadingpage and loginpage out of the shell and use App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell(); to navigate to mainpage when user login successfully.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT That is the problem. Page whose title is "Enrolamiento" should be the first page to be shown when app has not been executed before. I don't know why iOS shows other page. I have the condition in LoadingPage.xaml.cs. If user is authenticated, it should show MainPage. If not enrolled, it should show EnrolamientoPage and if user is enrolled, it should show LoginPage.To check if user is enrolled, I use bool enrolled = Preferences.Default.Get("enrolled", false);. and to check if user is authenticated, I use var hasAuth = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("hasAuth");.

The problem is you navigate to the EnrolamientoPage in the LoadingPage. I can't find the cause and can't reproduce it in a new project, you can report it on the github.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT what do you mean with "report it on github"? Any way... what's the problem of navigating from a page to another page? Why Android works?

If you remove the code about navigating in the LoadingPage, you can get correct UI. Report this as an new issue.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Do you mean the problem is n MAUI and not in my code? Navigating in LoadingPage is necessary to determine which page to show to the user.

I can't make sure. But you can put the loadingpage and loginpage out of the shell. And set the App.Current.MainPage to change the UI.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT I have installed VSCode in a Mac to try to debug the app, but when I run it, simulator is not executed. This error is shown instead: "The library 'libhostpolicy.dylib' required to execute the application was not found"

This is the full message: A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.dylib' required to execute the application was not found in ''.
The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[6441] DAttendance.dll' has exited with code 131 (0x83).

@LiyunZhang-MSFT I could finally debug using Visual Studio 2022 for Mac. When debugging, await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(EnrolamientoPage)}?initial=1"); loads the view and the corresponding view NavigatedTo method is called, however, finally the flyout page is shown. I think it is shown in front of the enrollment page, even when in that case, the Shell.Current.FlyoutBehavior is FlyoutBehavior.Disabled. I am not clear How the flyout is to be shown in iOS. In Android, it is a drawer coming from the left.

So you can reprot this as an new issue on the repo.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT which Repo?

Maui is an open source framework. You can report it on the github repo

Finally it was a problem in my code, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78116566/net-maui-shell-navigation-not-working-correctly-on-ios
